# add google maps in an android application

Tags: android, google-maps, exception

I'm new in Android development. I want to add Google maps to my application. I have done lots of searches but still the same problem arises when I run the application "Unfortunately , application has stopped"

So this is my java class

```
package com.example.hellomap;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_main);
        MapView map =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    }

}
```

the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellomap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hellomap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCKSp9pb7g8Wkga2SgeoT_MSe0JG59DkSU" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The LogCat shows:

```
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomap/com.example.hellomap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.example.hellomap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     ... 11 more
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     ... 20 more
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
04-03 13:45:42.574: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     ... 23 more
04-03 13:50:42.626: I/Process(1164): Sending signal. PID: 1164 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXCEPTION :- ClassNotFoundException
please check GooglePlayService Library Project First.

Second Thing You Can Not Type Cast Fragment To Map View, please read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

## Update:-

Follow The Step:-

1)Create New Project

2)Import GooglePlayService Library project into Your Workspace.

3)assign Google play Service library project as library project to your project

4)now add Map Fragment/Supported Map Fragment into your activity layout file

5)make sure this class found

how to check==>press control Key from keyboard and click on class name id you found      class then it's okay other wise fix it first.
i prefer to use Supported Fragment.

6)define all permission as describe in link i posted previously.

6)now its time to generate api key for map ,follow the step from given link.

Thanks i hope its help

Comment: I check the GooglePlayService Library what i should to write in the MainActivity.java , I replaced FragmentActivity to MapActivity